# Converting multiple variables to numeric using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am doing data clean-up in R.  There are multiple variables that are coded as char variables that I want to convert to numeric.  They are dollar amounts, so were defined as char variables when I loaded the CSV -- so, for example, I need to convert $123,456 to 123456.

To do this one variable at a time, I can use the following code, which works fine:

```
data2<-data
data2$'FY 2011' <- parse_number(data$'FY 2011')
```

However, I would like to loop over all the variables in the dataframe that need to be converted.  These variables are not all next to each other.  I tried to use a for loop, as follows:

```
#Duplicate dataset
data2<-data

#Define the variable names to loop over
x<-c('FY 2011', 'FY 2012', 'FY 2013', 'FY 2014')

#loop over the variable names, putting the converted values into the new dataset
for (var in x) {
  data2$var <- parse_number(data$var)
}
```

However, this does not work, giving me the error "Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'var'. "

I think this is because I am not putting the variable names into the loop in the right format.  However, I cannot figure out the correct format.  I know that there are ways to use lapply to apply a function to multiple variables, but I can't figure out a way of using this to put the output into a new dataset with the same variable names.  (I'm used to using Stata, where I find it quite easy to implement this sort of for loop to loop over variable names.)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Replace the `$`. with `[[` i.e. `data2[[var]] <- parse_number(data[[var]])`

Comment: `data2[var] <- lapply(data2[var], parse_number)` is a one-liner without the loop.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Both akrun and r2evans' solutions work!  Thank you -- I did not realize I could call variables with brackets.  Reposting them here for future readers:

Replace the $. with [[, i.e.

```
data2[[var]] <- parse_number(data[[var]])
```

A one-liner without the loop:

```
data2[var] <- lapply(data2[var], parse_number)
```